# Safari keywords?

Tags: safari

I'm looking to imitate the functionality of Firefox's keywords in Safari. That is, I want to be able to type `wp Apple` in the address bar, and Safari should go to the Wikipedia article on Apple. I found a Sourceforge project, [SafariKeywords](http://safarikeywords.sourceforge.net/), which does just this, but it was last updated in 2004 and doesn't work on Intel-based Macs.

Does the latest version of Safari have this functionality built in and I just didn't find it, or is there something like SafariKeywords I can use, or is this just a feature I'll have to live without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand this is an older thread, but for the next person who comes along, I recommend taking a look at [Safari Keyword Search](http://safarikeywordsearch.aurlien.net). It is a Safari extension that adds exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for checking in - I've marked your answer as read since indeed it's what I was looking for! I've since stopped using Alfred and Safari (I've been a Chrome user for many months now). :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you're looking, but this feature exists on [**Alfred**](https://www.alfredapp.com/). It's also on the [**Mac App Store**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alfred/id405843582?mt=12). And did I mention it's **free**?

[image: alfred app screenshot]

It's basically a spotlight replacement with a few twists. With it, you can set custom searches for any site you want:
[image: alfred app preferences]

The main advantage is that you can **search from anywhere you want**, you don't have to be on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Alfred, or another app launcher is a great option.

However, if you want to do this without hopping to another application, you can use a text expansion utility. That way, you type `wp` and it converts to `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=`. Then, you just have to type in your query and hit enter. This can be done with 10.6's built-in text replacement tool.

Go to the Language and Text System Preferences pane. Choose the Text tab. Click the plus button to create your new substitution rule.

Answer (score 1):

[SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) is a SIMBL plugin has this feature. They call it **QuickSearch**.

For your Wikipedia example (which I also use) you would add this search:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/@key

Comment: This is what I use as well. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

[Omnikey](http://marioestrada.github.io/safari-omnikey/), an extension for Safari does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing Alfred as was suggested, and I've come to like it! But I completely understand those of you who don't want to install a Spotlight alternative. I found a Safari plugin called [Keywurl](http://alexstaubo.github.com/keywurl/) which I think is exactly what I was looking for. I have not given it a try but the description fits the bill perfectly.

Also, if you give Keywurl a try with the latest Safari 5, you may have problems which [this blog post](http://hacketal.com/making-keywurl-work-with-safari-5) has addressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an ad-blocking proxy called [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/KeywordExpansion) that I have used to do this. However, while this gives you "two plugins in one", GlimmerBlocker occasionally has problems with new versions of Safari on Snow Leopard.